# How can i send login info in ExtJs proxy store?

Tags: java, extjs

How can i send login(username) as a parameter for store.load() method. I want to get this login on server and load only this user data.
I invoke load method in NotesGrid initComponent method, but i can't get login data from there (or I just don't know how to do this).
Also i tried invoke store.load() in onLoginSuccess method of LoginController, but then it doesn't work at all.

I know that i can use store.load({params:{login:'username'}})

But how can i send **login info** from LoginForm with store.load() call??

LoginController:

```
Ext.define('MVC.controller.LoginController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.login',

requires: [
    'MVC.view.Register',
    'MVC.view.Main'
],

views:[
  'MVC.view.Login'
],

init : function() {
    //control function makes it easy to listen to events on
    //your view classes and take some action with a handler function
    this.control({
        //when you click Submit button
        'login button[action=login]' : {
            click : this.onLoginClick
        }
    });
},

onLoginClick: function (button) {

    // This would be the ideal location to verify the user's credentials via
    // a server-side lookup. We'll just move forward for the sake of this example.
    var form = button.up('form').getForm();

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'login',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            loginData: Ext.encode(form.getValues())
        },
        scope: this,
        //method to call when the request is successful
        success: this.onLoginSuccess,
        //method to call when the request is a failure
        failure: this.onLoginFailure
    });
},

onRegisterClick: function () {
    this.getView().destroy();

    Ext.create({
        xtype: 'register'
    }).show()
},

onLoginFailure: function (err) {
    //Alert the user about communication error
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error occured during Login', 'Please try again!');
},

onLoginSuccess: function (response, opts) {
    //Received response from the server
    response = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    if (response.success) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Successful Login', response.message);

        this.getView().destroy();

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'main'
        });

    }
    else {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Login failed', response.message);
    }
}
});
```

GridView:

```
Ext.define('MVC.view.NotesGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype: 'notesGrid',

title: 'Note-list',

//  store: 'Notes',
store: 'TestStore',

initComponent: function(){
    this.callParent();
    this.on('render', this.loadStore, this);
},

loadStore: function() {
    this.getStore().load();
},

columns: [
    {
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1
    },
    {
        text: 'Creation Date',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'd-m-Y',
        dataIndex: 'createDate',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Last Modified',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'd-m-Y',
        dataIndex: 'modifiedDate',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Text',
        dataIndex: 'noteText',
        flex: 3
    }
]
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('MVC.store.TestStore', {
extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',

requires : [
    'MVC.model.Note'
],

storeId : 'TestStore',
model   : 'MVC.model.Note',
autoLoad: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'rest/notes',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});
```

Comment: If you are trying to build just a basic authentication system, it usually works like this: client sends login and password to a server, server verifies login and sets a session variable (usually session id cookie). Once user session is created you don't send the login info again in every request, instead your session cookie is getting sent along with each request and the server uses it to authenticate the user. You are using java for a backend, so you need to look into some authentication and session management framework you can use.

Comment: @serg Thank you for good advice, I completely forgot about session :D